# Reset primary id for nested/child resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an application I'm building that has albums with images.  I want the image's id to start at 1 when they are added to an album.  However, with my current setup, they don't reset for each album, but continue their numbering from one album to the next.

**Models**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :description, :album_id
   has_many :images,  :dependent => :destroy
   validates :title, :description, :presence => true
end


class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :description, :picture, :image_id, :album_id, :albumcover
   belongs_to :album
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :album
   mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader 
end
```

**Image Controller**

```
class Admin::ImagesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json
    def index
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @images = @album.images.all
    end
    def new
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new(params[:id])
    end
    def create
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new(params[:image]) 
        if @image.save
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully added image!"
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end
    def show
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
    end
    def edit
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
        if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
        else
            render :action => "edit"
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
        @image.destroy
        @albumid = @album.id
        @id = @image.id
        FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/image/picture/#{@albumid}/#{@id}", :force => true)
        redirect_to admin_album_images_path(@album)
    end

end
```

How do I make the numbering start at 1 within each album?

Answer (score 0):

"I want the image's id to start at 1"

The image_id field is a database identifier field that is likely auto-incrementing. It is based on the number of rows in the images table and has nothing to do with the association between image and album. It is probably not a good idea to have logic dependent on it.

I am curious why you want a serial number for images. For e.g., if you want to order your images within an album, one option would be:

```
album.images.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Another option is to add an extra column to your Images table called serial_number and manage it yourself.

If you can share what you want to achieve with the serial number, you will get better answers!

Comment: I want the id's to start afresh within each album mostly for order.  It's the same idea for comments on a blog post.  The first comment would be id 1, next is id 2, etc... That is what I want for the albums.  In each one, the first image is id 1, second is id 2, etc.

Comment: If you don't want to regroup your images, then I would use the suggestion by CubaLibre and then the `each_with_index` method while writing on screen. Try not to pollute your database with unneeded data.